# sqlite3 query for delete the specific id and reorder the remaining id's

Tags: sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebRv5.jpg) Delete a record which has Id:2 and Name:Gosling from the below shown table After deleting the records to be reordered by updating Id of all remaining records using below c code. But it it's not reordering instead it updating the same Id to all the record. Please help me out to resolve this issue. 
    Thanks in advance.

```
Before delete  

Id|Name | MacId| State | Type
-----------------------------
1|Dennis|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
2|Gosling|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
3|MOTO|4568971|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
4|KARBAN|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
5|Lenovo|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE

After deleting 2nd record It should be like as shown in the below table.   

Id|Name |MacId |State | Type
--------------------------------
1|Dennis|456731|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
2|MOTO|4568971|NOT CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
3|KARBAN|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
4|Lenovo|4568971|CONNECTED|NOT FAVORITE
```

deleteDevice() this method is to delete the record and update remaining Id.

```
 void deleteDevice(char deviceId, char *table)
    {
        sqlite3 *db;                                                                                                 
        char *err_msg = 0;                                                                                          
        sqlite3_stmt *res;
        char query[100];
        int rc = sqlite3_open("phonebook2.db", &db);  
        int lastDeveciId=getLastDeviceId(table);                                                                
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
        {                                                                                       
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));         
            sqlite3_close(db);        
            return;                                                                                                 
        }   
        sprintf(query,"delete from %s where DEVICE_ID =%d;",table,deviceId) ;      
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, NULL, 0, 0); 
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        enter code here
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fetch data: %s;\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_close(db);
            return;
        }
        if(lastDeveciId > deviceId)
        {
            for(int i=deviceId;i<lastDeveciId;i++)
            {
                sprintf(query,"update %s set DEVICE_ID=%d where DEVICE_ID =%d",table,i-1,i);
                printf("Query:%s\n",query);
                printf("Breakpoint\n");
                rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, NULL, 0, 0);
                update(table,i);
            }
        }  
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

    int main()
    {
        deleteDevice(0x02,"paired_phones");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: please, improve your question, it's very hard to understand, try to separate the sentences.

Comment: show us the table structure, what you want to mean with "reorder the remaining device id"?

Comment: @danilo reorder: Suppose I have 5 records in table If I delete the 2nd record from the table. then update the 3rd Id as 2nd , 4th as 3rd and 5ht as 4th and so on ....  Table structure :CREATE TABLE paired_phones(DEVICE_ID INTEGER UNIQUE,DEVICE_NAME TEXT NULL,DEVICE_MAC_ID TEXT NOT NULL,STATE TEXT NULL DEFAULT 'NOT CONNECTED',TYPE TEX NULL DEFAULT 'NOT FAVORITE' );

Comment: ids didn't work this way, but you can create a view, or a query to list the records getting the id's in order, and in your code you can treat the ids.

Comment: list of devices are displayed on the infotainment display from the above mentioned table .When you press on the device name on the display we get  Device Id as a request from the display . ex: If you pressed on 2 end device name to be deleted then Device Id will be 2. as you told "list the records getting the id's in order ". Now in table 2 end place 3 rd device, 3rd place 4th so on. If you want to delete 3rd device now actual Device Id in the table is 4.

Comment: it isn't a good practice to delete table records. create a field on your table: "active" or "deleted" or whatever name, and use to show or hide the devices.

Comment: when you had clicked to delete the device, then you update the table changing "active" field

Comment: Please have a look into the image which I updated in query. I have to display the  only paired phones. If I do so, as said above."list the records getting the id's in order". I will get the conflict on device Id because Device Id and S.No will be miss matched.

Comment: Look into display image, select whichever name want to be deleted we will get only S.No(1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5). Using this Id we need to delete the record. So I have to use this selected S.No as Device Id to delete the record. Because of this reason I am maintaining the S.No and Device Id both should be same. Please give suggestion on the same.